# gnome3 search layout broken

Tags: 18.04, gnome, ubuntu-gnome

After testing some themes the layout of the search is broken even on the default theme. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having the same exact issue.

I am using the Mojave GTK shell theme (https://github.com/vinceliuice/Mojave-gtk-theme).

I got it fixed by uninstalling (reverting) their GDM theme and rebooting:

```bsh
cd Mojave-gtk-theme
sudo ./install.sh -r
```